# how to crop pdf page using iTextsharp or Quickpdf without text cut issue?

Tags: vb6

Aim:

i want to crop the pdf based on the co-ordinates

Problem Description:

i have used Acrobat to crop the pdf based on the co-ordinate values.
it croping the pdf with out any text cut.Kindly refer the below code.But i need to do the task with out adobe professional. so is it possible with iTextSharp or Quickpdf?
With out adobe how to achieve the below task?

```
Private Function GetBoxSplit_pdf(ByVal sType As String, ByVal l As Long, ByVal t As Long, ByVal r As Long, ByVal B As Long, ByVal deadline As Long) As Long
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'This function is used to get the line break from a given rectangle
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'input for this function is rectangle quardinates
    'output of this function is position of word end or line end
    'when we find word end it should return a no of line also
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    On Error GoTo ErrMesg

    Dim ssword As String
    Dim myrect1 As Acrobat.CAcroRect
    Dim PDTextSelect1 As CAcroPDTextSelect
    Dim AVHilite As CAcroHiliteList
    Dim llinecount As Long
    Dim AcroRect As CAcroRect
    Dim AcroRect1 As CAcroRect

    Dim lReturnValue As Long
    '~~~ Acrobat Object Declaration~~~~~~~~
    Dim pdTextSelect As CAcroPDTextSelect
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    '~~~~~~~~ Line count Variables ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim lPrevLeft As Long
    Dim lPrevTop As Long
    Dim lPrevRight As Long
    Dim lPrevBottom As Long

    Dim bh As Long
    Dim lprevbh As Long
    bh = 0
    lprevbh = 0

    Dim lleft As Long, ltop As Long, lbottom As Long, lright As Long

    llinecount = 1
    '~~~~~~~~ Line count Variables ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Set AVHilite = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList")
    Set AcroRect = CreateObject("AcroExch.Rect")
    'Create a Rectangle object
    Set AcroRect1 = CreateObject("AcroExch.Rect")

    'Convert Image coordinates into Pdf Coordinates
    ConvertImgToPdf l, t, r, B

    'Assign the pdf co-ordinates to the rectangle object
    AcroRect.left = Abs(l)
    AcroRect.Top = Abs(t)
    AcroRect.Right = Abs(r)
    AcroRect.Bottom = Abs(B)

    'Set AcroExchApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    pdPage.CropPage AcroRect

    Set pdTextSelect = pdDoc.CreateTextSelect(0, AcroRect)
    num = pdTextSelect.GetNumText()

    'AcroExchApp.Show

    If (num > 0) Then
        iwordcount = 0
        ssword = ""
        For iwordcount = 0 To num - 1

            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Set AVHilite = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList")
            AVHilite.Add iwordcount, 1
            Set PDTextSelect1 = pdPage.CreateWordHilite(AVHilite)

            Dim i2 As Integer
            AcroExchAVDoc.SetTextSelection PDTextSelect1
            ssword = ""
            For i2 = 0 To PDTextSelect1.GetNumText - 1
                ssword = ssword & " " & PDTextSelect1.GetText(i2)
            Next
            If ssword <> "" Then
                Set myrect1 = PDTextSelect1.GetBoundingRect

                If iwordcount = 0 Then
                    lPrevBottom = myrect1.Bottom
                    lPrevLeft = myrect1.left
                    lPrevRight = myrect1.Right
                    lPrevTop = myrect1.Top
                    'bh = Abs(myrect1.Top - myrect1.Bottom)
                End If

                If Abs(lPrevBottom - myrect1.Bottom) > 5 And Abs(lPrevTop - myrect1.Top) > 5 Then
                    lprevbh = bh
                    bh = bh + Abs(lPrevTop - lPrevBottom)
                    llinecount = llinecount + 1
                    If myrect1.Bottom < B Then
                        lReturnValue = limageheight - lPrevBottom
                        'GetBoxSplit = limageheight - lPrevBottom
                        Exit For
                    End If

                End If
                lPrevBottom = myrect1.Bottom
                lPrevLeft = myrect1.left
                lPrevRight = myrect1.Right
                lPrevTop = myrect1.Top
            End If
            Set pdTextSelect = Nothing
            Set myrect1 = Nothing
            Set AVHilite = Nothing
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Next

    End If
    Set AcroRect = Nothing
    If lReturnValue = 0 Then
        lReturnValue = deadline
    End If
    GetBoxSplit_pdf = lReturnValue
    'GetBoxSplit = deadline
    Exit Function
ErrMesg:
    GetBoxSplit_pdf = deadline
    MsgBox "Error while Getting text" & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Function
```